# How to get clean urls using .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website which creates the following url

https://www.website.com/timings/result.php?city=Patna%2C+Bihar%2C+India&method=1

but I am willing to make it clean such as

https://www.website.com/timings/result/cityname or something similar.

Tried the following code but no luck.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ result.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ result.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Sorry but I followed the rule but failed to make any changes.

Comment: Your RewriteRule does not seem to contain `^timing/(\w+)$` or anything remotely specific to your case. This doesn't count as reasonable attempt, or worthy of posting a new question.